# visual studio 2017 adding extra dll in output \bin\debug

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Community, 2017, Version 15.1.  WPF app with win forms report control.  Just moved to SQLite from SQL Server.  Now have extra 21 files in \bin\debug (named Microsoft.VisualStudio.*.dll) such as Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSHelp.dll.  Manually removing these files, app runs fine.
Looked at NuGet config and all seems well.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking where they came from or whether it's okay to delete them?

Comment: Why are they there?  Should have made question clearer--the real problem is that these files 'Failed to copy' when publishing solution using ClickOnce framework.

Answer (score 13):

**Suggested Title** (I cannot edit) : Why Visual Studio 2017 adds Microsoft and Visual Studio dlls in bin folders (debug/release)

I've found the reason : **It is due to Microsoft Report Viewer 14**.

**To reproduce:**

- Create a new project, add any DLL you want (except Nuget for ReportViewer 14) and compile : no useless file.
- Then, add ReportViewer 14 : boom, tons of useless files.

**SOLUTION** :

- In your Project
- in the Reference section
- Select the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design library
- Set "copy Local" to FALSE
- This dll is not mendatory when you distribute your app.

To name a few (to help google searching) :

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility.dll, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.dll, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI.dll, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSHelp.dll  (there is like 20 DLLs with Microsoft.VisualStudio.*.dll)
```

Comment: THIS.   Thanks for answering.